# I need to set a separate Main Interface for iPhone and iPad, but Xcode only lets me set one interface for the project when it is universal

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-universal-app

[image]

I am unable to set a specific Main interface for iPad, even though my app is universal. Xcode used to have separate tabs for the Deployment Info on iPhone and iPad but now they are they same. However my game is radically different on iPhone and iPad and I need to set separate storyboards for each interface.

Someone please help if you know the solution.

Answer (score 2):

you could set the value in the `Deployment Info` -> `Main Interface` to an empty string and implement a custom logic in your `AppDelegate`:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
  // Override point for customization after application launch.

  UIStoryboard *initialStoryboard;
  if ([UIDevice currentDevice].userInterfaceIdiom == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
    initialStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
  } else {
    initialStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main_iPad" bundle:nil];
  }

  self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
  self.window.rootViewController = [initialStoryboard instantiateInitialViewController];
  [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

  return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use size classes for this. To select the correct size class, open your storyboard file, then click on this icon towards the bottom of the screen.

[image: Size class button]

Clicking wAny hAny will allow you to change the size class type and set specific constraints for the different device types. You can read more information about size classes [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-IB_adaptive_sizes/chapters/AboutAdaptiveSizeDesign.html)

Comment: But I don't want to use size classes.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply on this. Is there any reason why you don't want to use size classes?

Comment: It's just a subjective thing, I feel that the non-autolayout tools are way less of a hassle. Especially if I want to do a radically different interface on iPad than on iPhone. If you're curious about what the non-autolayout tools look like, here's a screenshot: http://i.imgur.com/r6f7GMB.png