# How to skip 2 ViewController correctly

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Tell me, please, what am I doing wrong?
There are 3 View:

1. The user selects his gender
2. The user enters his weight
3. Main View Application

After the user has written this data, he gets to the main screen of the application. I want to make the user choose his gender and weight only at the very first launch of the application. To do this, I created a UserSettings model to store the entered values there:

```
final class UserSettings {
    enum SettingsKeys: String {
        case userSex
        case userWeight
    }

    static var userSex: String! {
        get {
            return UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: SettingsKeys.userSex.rawValue)
        } 
        set {
            let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
            let key = SettingsKeys.userSex.rawValue
            if let sex = newValue {
                print("Пол \(sex) добавлен в \(key)")
                defaults.set(sex, forKey: key)
            } else {
                defaults.removeObject(forKey: key)
            }
        }
    }

    static var userWeight: String! {
        get {
            return UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: SettingsKeys.userWeight.rawValue)
        } 
        set {
            let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
            let key = SettingsKeys.userWeight.rawValue
            if let weight = newValue {
                print("Вес \(weight) добавлен в \(key)")
                defaults.set(weight, forKey: key)
            } else {
                defaults.removeObject(forKey: key)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In AppDelegate in function `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions` wrote:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
    let skipPageSex = defaults.bool(forKey: UserSettings.userSex)
    let skipPageWeight = defaults.bool(forKey: UserSettings.userWeight)

    if skipPageSex && skipPageWeight == true {
        let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let nextView: MainViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(identifier: "MainViewController") as! MainViewController
        window?.rootViewController = nextView
        self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    } else {
        let firstStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let firstView: WelcomeViewController = firstStoryboard.instantiateViewController(identifier: "welcomeVC") as! WelcomeViewController
        window?.rootViewController = firstView
        self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    }
    return true
 }
```

In the Sex select View in the button action, I wrote:

```
@IBAction func manSelected(_ sender: UIButton) {        
    sender.setTitle("Male", for: .normal)
    UserSettings.userSex = sender.currentTitle
    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
    defaults.setValue(true, forKey: UserSettings.userSex)
    defaults.synchronize()
}
```

And the same for the button with the female choice, only `sender.setTitle("Female", for: .normal)`
I tried removing `UIMainStoryboardFile` and `UIApplicationSceneManifest` in Info.plist and in this case I get just a black screen without errors. In the Storyboard ID I use the same value as in AppDelegate. Please, help

Comment: Please describe the problem you're having. Is it that after you select gender and weight `WelcomeViewController` still shows up not `MainViewController`?

Comment: No, when running the simulator, for some reason I have a black screen with the error Failed to instantiate the default view controller for UIMainStoryboardFile 'Main' - perhaps the designated entry point is not set? No View is displayed. And if I turn on the Is Initial View Controller setting, then the simulator always starts from the very first `WelcomeViewController`

Comment: Have you cleared Main Interface from Deployment Info since you're creating ViewController programmatically? Please refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33926239/i-need-to-set-a-separate-main-interface-for-iphone-and-ipad-but-xcode-only-lets) about it.

Comment: I cleared the Deployment Info -> Main Interface field and nothing has changed

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Try something like this. Initial with a TempViewController. Depend on your data, it will segue perform show Gender Picker or go directly to Main. Remember to check the Is Initial View Controller for root Navigation Controller.